# Strange TC_STRING error

Tags: php

I am running PHP 5.3.4 compiled from source with pcntl and posix.

I did update and some packages including php-process and php-cli were updated.

Then I ran my PHP daemon and it threw error -

> PHP Warning:  dl(): Dynamically loaded
>   extensions aren't enabled in
>   /var/www/html/includes/init.php on
>   line 27 PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Mongo' not found in
>   /var/www/html/includes/init.php on
>   line 29

The daemon ran fine before the update.

I searched a bit and changed the first line of the file to `#!/usr/bin/php -d enable_dl=On -q` from `#!/usr/bin/php -q`

Now, doing this throws this error

> PHP:  syntax error, unexpected
>   TC_STRING in Unknown on line 7

But the daemon works fine except the warning.

And it isn't making any sense to me. The 7th line of my script is just fine. What might this be?

Thank you all.

Comment: Does `exec("php -d enable_dl=On $argv[0]");` work ? Your error is due to passing parameters in the shebang line obviously. I'm unsure if this is a bug or not though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[function dl() is deprecated from 5.3 onwards](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php)

Comment: Translation: You shouldn't rely on `dl()` existing, and should instead always have extensions load via php.ini directly.